# How to read all files name in a dir under adb shell model

Tags: android, python-2.7, shell

I tend to read files name in a Android device beacuse I want to check the resource in this device is correct. Normally the order of manual testing is

```
adb -s 192.168.1.100:5555 root
adb -s 192.168.1.100:5555 shell
```

and when enter shell model， into the dir and `ls`

```
cd xxx\xxx\xxx
ls
```

Now I tend to write a python script to help me check it, so I try:

```
os.system('adb -s 192.168.1.100:5555 root')
obj = subprocess.Popen(["adb -s 192.168.1.100:5555 shell"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

and then I dont't know how to read  file name and put file name into a list. Without shell model I try:

```
file_list = os.listdir("xxx\xxx\xxx")

l = []
for file_name in file_list:
l.append(file_name)
```

It works, but how can I do this in shell model? I mean switch path to adb shell path, then I can use this code to put file name into a list. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print all the files in a particular directory in a shell, you can simply try this:

```
for i in *; do echo $i;done
```

Here is what you can put in your python file.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('for i in *; do echo $i;done', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print line,
```

This will get your task done.

Comment: This is works in adb shell model， but h ow can I change my model to adb model and then use this command (in a python file).

Comment: `procId = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', stdin = subprocess.PIPE) procId.communicate('list=$(for i in *; do echo $i;done) \nexit\n')`

Comment: This should work for your case. And please do upvote and mark it as solved if the above works.

Comment: Sorry again. I tried following code，but I still don't know how to use this variable`$list`. like I have a file name `123.py`in that path, how can I use this variable`$list` to check? `procId = subprocess.Popen('adb -s 192.168.1.100:5555 shell ', stdin = subprocess.PIPE)` 
`procId.communicate('list=$(for i in /mnt/media_rw/sdcard0/vol1; do echo $i;done) \nexit\n')`

Comment: So sorry. I am new on coding.@Abhishek Jain

Comment: I have updated the answer. This should get you going.

Comment: @shuoqi If it has solved your problem, please accept and close the question.